# batch backup that reads number from a text file doesn't work for values below 9

Tags: batch-file, version-control

The following code works when `version.txt` is **9 or greater** (tested for 98 to 101 and works as expected):

```
set /p Build=<version.txt
set /a NewBuild=%Build%+1
set TMP=backup_%Build%
if not exist "%TMP%" (
    @echo %NewBuild%> version.txt

    mkdir "%TMP%"
    cd "%TMP%"
    for /r "C:\xampp\htdocs\testzone\main" %%F in (*.*) do (
        cls
        if exist "%%F" (
            if not exist "%%~nxF" (
                xcopy /h "%%F" "%%~nxF"
                pause > nul
            )
        )
    )
)
```

But it won't work for values `1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7 or 8`, when I run the code with numbers from 1 to 8 the folder is created and everything is copied correctly but `version.txt` changes to an empty file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change

```
@echo %NewBuild%> version.txt
```

to

```
> version.txt @echo %NewBuild%
```

a sungle numeric directly before a redirector causes redirection of device#n (1=stdout, 2=stderr, 0=stdin, others not used.

Comment: it is now turning the `version.txt` to an empty file 1 to 8 and even numbers greater than 8

Comment: I managed to make it work with `(@echo %NewBuild%) > version.txt`